# Should the stats reported by Go's runtime.ReadMemStats approximately equal the resident memory set reported by ps aux?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

In Go Should the "Sys" stat or any other stat/combination reported by [`runtime.ReadMemStats`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats) approximately equal the resident memory set reported by `ps aux`?

Alternatively, assuming some memory may be swapped out, should the Sys stat be approximately greater than or equal to the RSS?

We have a long-running web service that deals with a high frequency of requests and we are finding that the RSS quickly climbs up to consume virtually all of the 64GB memory on our servers. When it hits ~85% we begin to experience considerable degradation in our response times and in how many concurrent requests we can handle. The run I've listed below is after about 20 hours of execution, and is already at 51% memory usage.

I'm trying to determine if the likely cause is a memory leak (we make some calls to CGO). The data seems to indicate that it is, but before I go down that rabbit hole I want to rule out a fundamental misunderstanding of the statistics I'm using to make that call.

This is an `amd64` build targeting `linux` and executing on `CentOS`.

Reported by `runtime.ReadMemStats`:

```
Alloc:     1294777080 bytes (1234.80MB)  // bytes allocated and not yet freed
Sys:       3686471104 bytes (3515.69MB)  // bytes obtained from system (sum of XxxSys below)
HeapAlloc: 1294777080 bytes (1234.80MB)  // bytes allocated and not yet freed (same as Alloc above)
HeapSys:   3104931840 bytes (2961.09MB)  // bytes obtained from system
HeapIdle:  1672339456 bytes (1594.87MB)  // bytes in idle spans
HeapInuse: 1432592384 bytes (1366.23MB)  // bytes in non-idle span
```

Reported by `ps aux`:

```
%CPU %MEM       VSZ      RSS 
1362 51.3 306936436 33742120
```

Comment: Sys-HeapReleased should roughly correlate with RSS, but there's no guarantee that what the program says it's using matches what the OS provides.

Comment: @JimB Thank you. I didn't list the HeapReleased stat here, but it was zero. I think it's fair to say that 30GB RSS doesn't "roughly correlate" with 3.5GB reported by Sys, giving credence to the memory leak hypothesis. 

One further avenue I could investigate is what happens to HeapReleased as we approach 100% memory usage in RSS. It actually seems to top out at 85% so likely that's where the OS starts swapping, explaining some of the performance degradation. If it starts releasing heap at that point, then it would indicate Go's GC is somehow aware of the problem.

Comment: What version of Go are you using? I think stacks used to get missed in some stats, and also couldn't be released. Get a stack trace and see what goroutines you have running, as you're likely leaking some from each request.

Comment: @JimB Using Go 1.6. I've kept a fairly close eye on the profiles and nothing is out of the ordinary. We average about 35k goroutines with about 3-5k of them blocked at any given moment. Most of them blocked in IO wait as the http request comes in. That doesn't change as these stats get worse. When our response times degrade we start pruning requests (the nature of our application allows us to ignore some requests if necessary) which keeps that number fairly static.

Comment: Sounds like the memory is allocated via cgo then.

Comment: @JimB I eliminated cgo from the equation today--didn't help. So strange!